# how can I change the read more link destinations and direct all to the same page?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, read-more

I have 4 read more urls in my woocommerce product listing and i would like all to be directed to a custom page instead of the product info page - preferably using functions.php

Comment: You could try the [excerpt_more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_more/) filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the post_link filter to rewrite the permalinks for those selected products.

```
function redirect_products( $url, $post ) {

    if ( in_array($post->ID, array(1,2,3,4) ) { //1,2,3,4 = your product IDs
        $url = get_permalink(123); //the ID of the redirect page 
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'redirect_products', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This almost works thanks. Can I do it based upon category instead? get_the_category?